# python3 pandas get specific row and specific column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The goal is to take a data frame that prints like this:

```
     Tag  Posts
0  metal  27323
1 plastic 11192
```

But only get the value:

```
27323
```

**IMPORTANT: I CAN NOT USE A NUMERICAL VALUE TO FIND THE ROW. THE ROW MUST BE LOCATED BY TAG NAME THEN COLUMN "POSTS" RETRIEVED FROM THAT ROW TO RETURN 27323**

Here is what I have been trying:

```
tag = ['metal', 'plastic']
num = ['27323', '11192']

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Tag': tag,
        'Posts': num,
    })

# Then write data to csv file
df.to_csv('tag_data.csv', index=False)

# Read that csv file but only retrieve the row for 'metal'
read_csv = pd.read_csv('tag_data.csv', names='metal')

# Then retrieve the column for 'num'
print(read_csv.loc[0,'Posts'])
```

This returns this error:

```
"cannot do {form} indexing on {type(self)} with these "
TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [0] of <class 'int'>
```

Thanks for taking the time to help me if you can.

Comment: Why do you save the dataframe to a file and then _incorrectly_ read it back instead of extracting the value directly from the dataframe?

Comment: @DYZ Because when all is said and done that will be a huge file that I will need to parse the same way over and over for different tag names.

Comment: ```df.loc[df["Tag"].eq("metal"), "Posts"]```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read the file incorrectly. Do not pass the `names='metal'` option, it makes one of the columns have the name "metal" rather than "Tag". Once you fix that, here's the answer:

```
read_csv.loc[read_csv.Tag == 'metal', 'Posts']
# 0    27323
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense but it returns  "0    27323"  along with "Name: Posts, dtype: int64" is it possible to have it only return "27323" thank you.

Comment: Use ```df.loc[...].to_numpy()[0]```

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski Bingo!!

Comment: i would like to mark this answered because @GrzegorzSkibinski added the last bit to make the above answer perfect but it would seem confusing

Comment: You never mentioned the desired output format. Once the data are selected from a dataframe, you can convert it to an array or any format.

Answer (score 0):

```
tag = ['metal', 'plastic']
num = ['27323', '11192']

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'num': num,

    },index=tag)

print(df.loc['plastic','num'])
```

This will give you what you need.

Comment: That's no problem. Save it as follows: df.to_csv('tag_data.csv') and read then: read_csv = pd.read_csv('tag_data.csv',index_col=0)